# Is it possible to run a Java program inside a Flex application?

Tags: java, apache-flex

I would like to be able to incorporate a simple game, written in Java as a component within a Flex Application.  Am I crazy?

Flex can display HTML, and SWF, it can also call JavaScript - but can I incorporate an applet somehow?

I do NOT mean kludging it in as a sister component within a browser, but actually within the flex application itself, so that it could also run under Adobe Air, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Flash doesn't have a JVM.  You would need to convert your Java to ActionScript somehow.

Comment: Johannes, that just makes me sad.

Answer (score 0):

Running a Flex application inside a Java program is possible, not the opposite.
It might be possible to compile a Java Virtual Machine (if it's written in C) using [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)... but I don't think you want to go there, converting your code would be easier and cleaner ;)